# Can't make changes with _theme.less

Tags: theme, magento2.2

I'm developing my own theme and I added some styling in `_theme.less` which I have put in `app/design/frontend/MyVendor/mytheme/Magento_Theme/web/css/source/_theme.less`. No style changes are updated when doing styling in `_theme.less`. I've tried deleting the static files and cleaning the cache as well.

I can make CSS changes when adding my own `.css` file in `default_head_blocks.xml` but not when trying to use `_theme.less`. Not sure what the problem is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To take effect new changes, first of all, you should delete your var/view_preprocessed/pub and pub/static/frontend folders and files using below command :

```
rm -rf pub/static/frontend/ var/view_preprocessed/pub/
```

After that you should deploy your static content :

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

then you would see changes you made in _theme.less file.

However, I would recommend you should extend styling using _extend.less, because if you want to use _theme.less file then, first of all, you have to copy all styling which is in Magento luma _theme.less file. And if in future that file changes then you should again copy all content of Magento luma _theme.less file into your _theme.less file.

so the recommendation is to use _extend.less. But in your case above commands will solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you haven't compiled LESS to CSS. How to do this depends on your workflow, for example this could be `setup:static-content:deploy` or `grunt exec && grunt less`.

Comment: I thought LESS compilation was already implemented in Magento 2? In admin, my workflow type is already set to "Server side less compilation" and I am developing with developer mode. I tried setup:static-content:deploy -f but no changes were made. I'm still new to Magento development but the devdocs says that it should work by just adding the _theme.less file. http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-preprocess.html

Comment: You have it mixed up, server side means you manually compile. And client-side is where it injects a JS file that will compile on each page load.

Comment: Yes that's correct. I followed up on it afterwards. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The `_theme.less` file is must move in this path `/app/design/frontend/MyVendor/mytheme/web/css/source/`, and after that you must run this commands:

```
rm -rf pub/static/frontend/* var/view_preprocessed/*
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: I updated my question with the full path I have used and I have executed that command without any changes. No idea what I'm doing wrong

Comment: The path of your `_theme.less` file is not correct, see the correct path in my answer.

Comment: Magento 2.2 devdocs says to use  `/<Namespace>_<Module>/web/css `. [Source](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-themes.html#How-Magento-stylesheet-files-are-organized)

Comment: Yes, but you say "I'm developing my own theme" :)